# Trying to make multiple columns

Tags: html, css, tumblr

The problem is pretty basic. I'm having trouble making a single column theme into a two-column theme. It can usually be done by just increasing the width of #entries (the container for .posts), but its not working in this case. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/1eawa859/1/
CSS

```
#entries {
margin-left: 385px; 
width: 700px;
background: transparent;
}

.posts {
width: 250px; 
padding: 10px;
background: transparent; 
}

.posts img {
max-width: 250px;
height: auto;
}
```

No matter how wide I make the container, the posts refuse to expand more than just a single column for some reason. I tried inserting float:left, but different size posts would be completely flush from the top (I'm going for a grid style). Hopefully that makes some sense.

```
<div id="entries">
{block:Posts}
<div class="posts">

{block:Photo}
{LinkOpenTag}
<a href="{Permalink}">
<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" class="postpic"/>
</a>
{LinkCloseTag}
{/block:Photo}

{block:Photoset}
{block:IndexPage}
{block:Photos}
<a href="{Permalink}" title="{NoteCountWithLabel}">
<img src="{PhotoURL-250}"></a>
{/block:Photos}
{/block:IndexPage}
{/block:Photoset}

</div>
{/block:Posts}

{block:PostNotes}
<div class="ending">{PostNotes}</div>
{/block:PostNotes}
</div>
```

Comment: Post your HTML markup as well

Comment: And ideally create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something of the sort to provide a live example and make it easier for us to test things out.

Comment: @Auburn you have incorect HTML markup. You are only allowed 1 unique ID per page.

Comment: @Auburn your markup is still wrong! you cannot have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1eawa859/2/ Good?

Comment: @Auburn ok so what container do you want to make 2 columns with?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want 2 `.posts` next to each other in a `#entries`, right?
Use `float`; but like you said you get unwanted behavior in height. `Inline-block`s might be a solution. Or just `clear` every odd float, so every 1st/3rd/etc is on a new line.
Or use `Flexbox` to make .posts 1 and 2 be the same height.
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Inline block doesn't seem to work for whatever reason. How would I implement the clear into the code, though? Would `.posts:nth-child(odd) {
clear: both;` work?

Comment: `.posts:nth-child(odd)` should work, but it's only IE9+. You could also set a class server-side or with JS?
Remember the 4px space between inline-block divs!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the width of `entries` to a specific `px` you should use `%`

If you want to keep your padding try this as your CSS markup :

```
.posts {
    width: calc(50% - 20px) /*20px for the 10px padding on each side*/ 
    padding: 10px;
    background: transparent; 
}
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc calc is only IE10+, so i wouldn't go for calc just yet.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the widht-property from your .posts class:

```
.posts {
  padding: 10px;
  background: transparent;
}
```

Second, add another entry to your css markup:

```
.posts div {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

This will allow you to automagically align as many items as fit within the given posts width.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This gives me the same problem as when I tried implementing the float property unfortunately. Except now, the images are flush from the bottom instead of the top. http://i.imgur.com/BfDQyZX.png

Comment: Ok, just realized (at least part) of your problem when I looked at your fiddle. You are setting the .posts wrapper to width:250px, the elements inside that cannot align wider than 250px, even though the outer wrapper is wider. I don't think I can add code here, so I'll add another entry below instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a jQuery plugin, that makes your posts align into a grid system. I, and a lot of other tumblr theme makers, use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), but there are other plugins as well.

It's pretty simple, if you are a bit familiar with jQuery plugins. You need a container (#entries), and a class for the posts, I called them "entry". Then you add the Masonry code.

I edited your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/riverbell/1eawa859/4/

```
var $container = $('#entries');
// initialize
$container.masonry({
  columnWidth: 270,
  itemSelector: '.entry'
});
```

This is just the basics, you can read about all the options on the Masonry web page.

The tumblr markup:

```
<div id="entries">
{block:Posts}
<div class="entry">

{block:Photo}
{LinkOpenTag}
<a href="{Permalink}">
<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" class="postpic"/>
</a>
{LinkCloseTag}
{/block:Photo}

{block:Photoset}
{block:IndexPage}
{block:Photos}
<a href="{Permalink}" title="{NoteCountWithLabel}">
<img src="{PhotoURL-250}"></a>
{/block:Photos}
{/block:IndexPage}
{/block:Photoset}

</div>
{/block:Posts}

{block:PostNotes}
<div class="ending">{PostNotes}</div>
{/block:PostNotes}
</div>
```

Depending on how many columns you want, you can alter the width of the container element; #entries.

Good luck!